# Bacon in sealed package, 4 days at room temp

Tags: food-safety

I bought 4 packages of vacuum packed bacon 4 days ago, left them on the counter at room temperature by mistake. I opened them tonight, they smelled fine, color was good, bacon was not slimy. I cooked a piece and ate it, tasted fine. Is this bacon OK to eat? (too late for me...)

Comment: What does the label say on the package? Does it require refrigeration?

Comment: The label says to refrigerate but the fact is there is no discoloration or odor. Also, I ate some last night and I'm fine.

Comment: Lack of discoloration and odor means nothing. Glad to hear you're fine but I really can't imagine why you'd take that level of risk just for a piece of bacon.

Comment: Good question. How do you feel today?

Answer (score 3):

Modern bacon is insufficiently cured to preserve it--or perhaps it is more accurate to say that you are not guaranteed that it *is* sufficiently cured.

You should discard this product.